# How to map kinect skeleton data to a model?

Tags: kinect, skinning, openni

I have set up a Kinect device and written a simple program that reads the stream to a QImage using OpenNI 2.0. I have set up skeleton tracking with NiTE 2.0, so I have access to the coordinates of all the 15 joints. I have also set up a simple scene using SceniX. The hand coordinates provided by the skeleton tracking are beeing used to draw 2 boxes to represent the hands.

I would like to bind the whole skeleton to a (rigged)model, and cant seem to find any good tutorials. Anyone have any idea how I should proceed?

Answer (score 1):

depending on your requirements you could look at something like this for Unity Engine https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10693

There is also a Plugin for the Unreal 4 Engine called KINECT 4 UNREAL FROM OPAQUE MULTIMEDIA

But if you have to write it all by hand for yourself, i have done something similar using OpenGL.
I used Assimp http://assimp.sourceforge.net/ to be able to load animated Collada models and OpenNi with NiTE for skeletal tracking. I then used the rotation data from the Nite skeleton and applied it to the corresponding Bones of my rigged mesh, overwriting the rotation values of the animation. Don't use positional Data. It will strech your bones and distort the mesh.
There are many sources for free 3D Models, like TF3DM.com . I for myself used a custom Rig for my models to be suitable for my code. So you might look into using Blender and how to Rig a Model.
Also remember that the Nite Skeleton has no joint for the Pelvis, and that Nite joints don't inherit their parents rotation, contrary to the bones in a rigged model.

I hope this helps to have something to go on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try DigitalRune, they have examples of binding a rigged model to joints. They have mentioned some examples too. try http://www.digitalrune.com/Support/Blog/tabid/719/EntryId/155/Research-Augmented-Reality-with-Microsoft-Kinect.aspx

Also you would need to know to animate model in blender and export it to XNA or to your working graphics framework. Eg:-http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/230540/Animating-single-bones-in-a-Blender-3D-model-with#SkinningSampleProject132